# Sending an automatic email based on cell value

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this code that I have cobbled together but, sadly I am stuck I can’t seem to work out how to only have the email addresses for overdue entries in the BCC.

I want it to create a single email to multiple email addresses from a list of emails that have a due date that is overdue and a previous email hasn't already been sent.

```
Sub Over_due()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
    strbody = "Text goes here"
    
    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
        If Cells(lRow, 6) <> "Email Sent" Then
            If Cells(lRow, 5) <= Date Then
            
            Set xOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set xMailItem = xOutlook.CreateItem(0)
                                
    For Each rng In Range("C:C")
        If rng.Value Like "*@*" Then
            If xEmailAddr = "" Then
                xEmailAddr = rng.Value
            Else
                xEmailAddr = xEmailAddr & ";" & rng.Value
            End If
        End If
     Next
     
    On Error Resume Next
               With xMailItem
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = xEmailAddr
        .Subject = Range("A1").Value
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        '.Attachments.Add
        .Display
        End With
        MsgBox "E-mail successfully created", 64
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set Mail_Object = Nothing

                Cells(lRow, 6) = "Sent email"
                Cells(lRow, 7) = "" & Now()
            End If
        
        
        
        End If
    Next
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So, what is the question excatly? BTW, you never use an object  `Mail_Object` but you have the line `Set Mail_Object = Nothing`! What is that good for? You also check `If Cells(lRow, 6) <> "Email Sent" Then` but then have a statement `Cells(lRow, 6) = "Sent email"` which menas the condition you check for will never be met unless someone changed the value of the cell manually to `Email Sent`.

Comment: The question is:  to be able to send an email automatically to all recipients that have an overdue date.

Comment: That is not a question, that is what you want to do. So, what is the question regarding the code you posted and where do you have a problem? I gave you some hints what seems to be an issue in your code! Did you have a look at that?

Comment: So, you just copied and pasted the code without understaning what it does? Is it that what you are saying?

Comment: if a cell is populated with "email Sent" in column "F" and Date sent "G" is populated then I don't want to send another email, but, only recipients who have a new over due date that haven't had an email sent previously.  Set Mail_Object = Nothing - I had cobbled together the code from previously posted code, I have just kept it in until I have worked out how to do this step first

Comment: I only have limited knowledge, and yes I don't fully understand the code (((shamed)))

Comment: Then try to nail down your issues with the code to single questions. A lot of people could write you code which does what you want to do but this will noit help you in understaning the code and even doing it yourself. Regarding my note `Email sent` and `Sent emai`: it seems you did noit get my point. Your code will send another email because you check for `Email sent` which is different from `Sent email`.

Comment: My question is how do I get the email addresses in xEmailAddr for only recipients that have an overdue date and hasn't had an email sent already?

Comment: Sorry, that is your request and I already gave you a hint what is possibly wrong in your code.

Comment: Email sent which is different from Sent email.- sorry typo!

Comment: What do you mean with typo? Are you saying the code you posted is not the code you use.

Comment: The code is the code I am using, however, I realised the error in the wording "email sent" when you pointed it out (thank you) I was more concerned with creating the email, which does work as far as an email is created but, for all recipients irrespective of the date being overdue, it also creates multiple emails every time I accept the message  "e-mail successfully created" when one email will suffice.  Admittedly, I don't know enough about coding to do it myself hence why I asking for help.

Comment: This is frequently seen but before using code with `On Error Resume Next` followed by `With xMailItem` you **must** immediately delete `On Error Resume Next`. This advice applies to most other instances of `On Error Resume Next` you see.

Answer (score 0):

I use a sub which automatically creates emails. and call it from various other subs - might come in handy:

```
Sub SendEmail(Optional ToAddresses As String, Optional CcAddresses As String, _
Optional BccAddresses As String, Optional Subject As String, _
Optional Body As String, Optional AttachFiles As Variant = False, Optional AutoSend As Boolean = False)

'RULES:
'    Where there are multiple Addresses in ToAddresses, CCAddresses 
'      etc, they have to be separated by a semicolon
'    AttachFiles should either be a string containing the full 
'      filename including the path, or (for multiple files) an array 
'      of same.
'    Body can be HTML or just plain text.

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .to = ToAddresses
        .CC = CcAddresses
        .Bcc = BccAddresses
        .Subject = Subject
        
        If Body Like "*</*>*" Then
            .HtmlBody = Body
        Else
            .Body = Body
        End If
        
        If Not AttachFiles = False Then
            If IsArray(AttachFiles) Then
                For x = LBound(AttachFiles) To UBound(AttachFiles)
                    .Attachments.Add (AttachFiles(x))
                Next
            Else
                .Attachments.Add (AttachFiles)
            End If
        End If
        
        If AutoSend = True Then
            .Send
        Else
            .Display
        End If
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

It's not totally my code, I adapted it from [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail4.htm).
It won't completely solve your problem, but it might condense it down to something simpler and more like:

```
Sub OverDue()
Dim strBody as String
Dim Row as Long
Dim lLastRow as Long

StrBody = "Text here"

lLastRow = UsedRange.Rows.Count 

For a = 2 to lLastRow
    If Cells(a, 6) <> "Email Sent" And Cells(a, 5)<= Date Then 'This checks each row to see if that person needs an email
'        DO STUFF HERE
'        Either Call the other sub separately each time 
'        (which can allow for more personalised messages, like a mail merge), 
'        or add the person's email address to a string and call the sub
'        after the loop.
Next

End Sub
```

Over to you to work out the rest of the details though!!

Comment: By the way, note that all the parameters in `SendEmail()` are optional, so you don't have to input them all. Calling the sub without any parameters at all will just pop up a blank email for you to fill out!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code like that

```
    Sub Over_due()
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim lLastRow As Long
        Dim lRow As Long
        Dim rng As Range
        
        Dim strbody As String
        Dim xOutlook
        Dim xMailItem
        Dim xEmailAddr
        
        
        strbody = "Text goes here"
        
        lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
            If Cells(lRow, 6) <> "Email Sent" Then
                If Cells(lRow, 5) <= Date Then
                
                    Set xOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                    Set xMailItem = xOutlook.CreateItem(0)
                                    
    '                For Each rng In Range("C:C")
    '                    If rng.Value Like "*@*" Then
    '                        If xEmailAddr = "" Then
    '                            xEmailAddr = rng.Value
    '                        Else
    '                            xEmailAddr = xEmailAddr & ";" & rng.Value
    '                        End If
    '                    End If
    '                Next

    'Do you really want to have all emails addresses in BCC because thats what you are doing
    'I changed the above code to the following lines which will not take the complete column 
                    Set rng = Range("C2:C" & lRow)
                    xEmailAddr = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng), ",")
         
                    On Error Resume Next
                    With xMailItem
                        .To = ""
                        .CC = ""
                        .BCC = xEmailAddr
                        .Subject = Range("A1").Value
                        .HTMLBody = strbody
                        '.Attachments.Add
                        .Display
                    End With
                    MsgBox "E-mail successfully created", 64
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    ' I changed that to Email Sent otherwise it will create the mai over and over again
                    Cells(lRow, 6) = "Email Sent"
                    Cells(lRow, 7) = "" & Now()
                End If
            
            
            
            End If
        Next
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```